# uWSGI process doesn't inherit permissions associated with group its uid belongs to

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a folder that I want to write to from a Django app using uwsgi (served by NGINX).  I set ownership on that folder to `root:writinggroup` and set permissions on that folder to 775.  I add the `www-data` user to the group `writinggroup`.

Then in my uwsgi ini file, I set:

```
uid = www-data
```

But when I run my server and hit the appropriate URL to trigger the write operation, I get a permissions error.

But if I switch the ownership of the folder to `www-data:writinggroup`, everything works perfectly.

So what's going on here?  Why is it that having the user-owner of the folder set to `www-data` gets the job done, while setting the group-owner of the folder to `writinggroup` doesn't even though `www-data` (the user) is a member of that group?

Basically, what I'm asking is: if you set uid but not gid in the uwsgi config, why doesn't the uwsgi process behave like it inherits permissions associated with groups to which that uid belongs?

Comment: [Possibly helpful](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76634).

Comment: It was an interesting read, but I coudldn't figure out the upshot.  How can I run uwsgi so that it behaves like it has all the premissions associated with all of the groups to which its uid belongs?

Comment: Or, more generally, is there any way to run any process so that it has all the permissions associated with all of the groups to which its uid belongs?  Or is every process permissioned only with the rights of its uid owner and its specific gid owner (so that if that uid is a member of 3 groups, it only gets the permissions of the one group whose gid is associated with that particular process and not the two other groups to which it belongs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on dgel's suggestion to learn about Unix permissioning: when you run processes in Unix, there are basically 3 ways you can wind up being "green lit" permissions-wise by the OS.

1. The user calling the command can be user-permissioned for the disk operation (green-lit because of effective user id)
2. The group id associated with the process can be group-permissioned for the disk operation (green-lit because of effective group id)
3. The user calling the command can be a member of a group that is group-permissioned for the disk operation (green-lit because of supplementary group id)

Number 3 there is important.  It's how a lot of disk operations are ultimately green-lit.  I.e. user `joe` is a member of group `awesome`.  Folder `important` is owned by `root:awesome` with permissions 775.  You execute a command at the terminal as `joe` where you try to write to `important`.  This will be run with user `joe` and likely with effective group id `joe` (i.e. the group that contains only the user `joe`).  Alone, this wouldn't get the job done.  But because `joe` is in `awesome` and `awesome` the group has write permissions, your command is able to succeed.

When you run uWSGI in emperror mode, you can set a uid and gid for your vassal processes.  I had assumed that this would result in vassals with the 3 types of permissions described above.  But that's not quite right.  While the vassals do indeed run with the effective user ID and effective group ID you specify, they *do not* wind up with any supplementary group ID's associated to their processes.

So say you have uWSGI running with `uid=www-data` and `gid=www-data` and you want to write to the `important` folder described above.  So you make `www-data` a member of `awesome`.  This will *not* be sufficient, because the vassal process will have *only* the permissions of `www-data` the user and `www-data` the group and *not* the permissions of the groups to which `www-data` (the user) belongs...i.e. it will *not* inherit the permissions of the `awesome` group.  This leads to the annoying behavior that commands executed at the terminal after switching users to `www-data` may succeed while code run by the above-configured uWSGI process will fail (because at the terminal the command gets the permissions of the `awesome` group, but the vassals do not).

One solution would be to change the ownership of the `important` folder to be `www-data:awesome`.  But I hate that answer since it doesn't generalize to a case where multiple users might need this kind of access.  Instead, there's a better way: there is an `add-gid` option for uWSGI.  So you would need to specify:

```
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
add-gid = awesome
```

in your uWSGI configuration.  This parameter can be set many times so that you can associate as many supplementary groups with your vassal processes as your heart desires.  You can read about it in the uWSGI release notes [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Changelog-1.9.15.html).

A very important note is that this parameter was only added in uWSGI 1.9.15.  This is *much newer* than the version that ships with Ubuntu.  So if you (like me) are in that situation, you'll need to upgrade uWSGI.  I did that with:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/uwsgi /usr/bin/uwsgi.bak
sudo pip install -U uwsgi
sudo ln -fs /usr/local/bin/uwsgi /usr/bin/uwsgi
```

Quick server reboot (`sudo service uwsgi restart`) and I was all set!

Comment: Too bad `add-gid` stopped working with vassals/emperor it seems. You'll have to use `--emperor-tyrant-initgroups` in the main uwsgi (not the vassals) configuration.

Comment: @Karolyi, is that a deliberate (documented) change in a recent release, or just an observation in context?  Curious if I need to worry about this fix breaking for me on a future upgrade.

Comment: I have no idea, as I have not used `add-gid` before. When searching around for solutions, I bumped into an issue on github that talked about this option, tried it and worked.